# R Server on the cloud visit local data on a firewalled office computer

Tags: ssh, cloud, alibaba-cloud

I want to use R Server constructed on a Ubuntu system on the Alibaba Cloud to do some elastic computing. The data is on the office computer, which has a firewall to prevent information leaking. I want to update the data to the cloud server for analysis.

I tried WINscp. It won't connect to the server (Connection timeout). I also tried PuTTY, which didn't work, either.

Could this be because of the Firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that your office has firewall rules in place to prevent data leaking, it is possible that your office firewall has blocked outbound traffic to port 22 (SSH), which is required to connect to your Ubuntu ECS instance running on Alibaba Cloud.

You should try to connect to your Ubuntu ECS instance from other locations without your office's firewall and see if it works.

Alibaba Cloud's ECS instance allows in-bound traffic access to port 22 by default based on their product page as below.

Source: [Default security group rules](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/31707.htm)

> The security group created by
>   the system has only rules for access over all ICMP ports, TCP Port 22,
>   and TCP Port 3389, of which,
>
> 1. All ICMP ports are used by network devices, including routers, to send
>      error messages and operational information.
> 2. TCP Port 22 is used to connect to a Linux instance using SSH.
> 3. TCP Port 3389 is used to remotely connect to a Windows instance using Windows Remote Desktop.